# Paginate via PHP vs MySQL best practice?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pagination

When dealing with records of at least 1 million rows, in terms of performance, is it better to:

Select the whole record e.g., `SELECT * FROM tbl` then paginate the result using `array_chunk()` or `array_slice()`

or

Select only part of the record e.g., `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT x` per page?

Comment: @RyanVincent Since performance is the topic, large record is assumed.

Comment: @RyanVincent why do you keep erasing your comments

Answer (score 1):

i think it depends, you can stock the whole response in the memory using memcache if your table is not too big and it will avoid HDD request which is more time consuming, but as you dont know if your user will look for lot of pages, it would be better to limit it with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

1. Does data change often in this table?

Yes -> you need query DB.

2. Is database big and changes often?

Then use some kind of search engine like Elasticsearch and don't query DB just populate search engine

3. Is database small but queries take long time?

Use some kind of cache like redis/memcache

It really depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The best method will depend on your context. If you choose to use the database directly, beware of this issue:

The naive LIMIT method will give you problems when you get into later pages. ORDER BY some_key LIMIT offset,page_size works like this - go through the key, through away the first *offset* records, then return *page_size* records. So *offset + page_size* records examined, if *offset* is high you have a problem.

Better -  remember the last key value of the current page. When fetching next page use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE the_key > $last_key ORDER BY the_key ASC LIMIT $page_size
```

If your key is not unique, make it unique by adding an extra unique ID column at the end.

Comment: Yes, this is better than using `OFFSET`.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Answer (score 1):

It REALLY depends on context.

In general you want to make heavy use of indexes to select the content that you want out of a large dataset with fast results.  It's also faster to paginate through the programming language than to use the database.  The database is often times the bottleneck.  We had to do it this way for an application that had 100's of queries a minute.  Hits to the database needed to be capped so we needed to return datasets that we knew may not need another query to the DB, around 100 results, and then paginate by 25 in the application.

In general, index and narrow your results with these indexes and if performance is key with lots of activity on the db, tune your db and your code to decrease I/O and DB hits by paginating in the application.  You'll know why when your server is bleeding with a load of 12 and your I/O is showing 20 utilization.  You'll need to hit the operating table stat!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use LIMIT.   think about it.. The first one will get all even if you have 1000000 rows.  vs limit which will only get your set number each time.

You will then want to make sure you have your offsets set correctly to get the next set of items from the table.